# OpenShift RestAPI Equivalent of oc tag

Tags: rest, docker, openshift

What is the OpenShift RestAPI equivalent of `oc tag some.docker.regiery some-image-tag:latest`?

From the help page:

```
Tag existing images into image streams 

The tag command allows you to take an existing tag or image from an image stream, or a Docker image pull spec, and set
it as the most recent image for a tag in 1 or more other image streams. It is similar to the 'docker tag' command, but
it operates on image streams instead. 

Pass the --insecure flag if your external registry does not have a valid HTTPS certificate, or is only served over HTTP.
Pass --scheduled to have the server regularly check the tag for updates and import the latest version (which can then
trigger builds and deployments). Note that --scheduled is only allowed for Docker images.

Usage:
  oc tag [--source=SOURCETYPE] SOURCE DEST [DEST ...] [flags]
```

Comment: Have you tried running the `oc tag` command with `--loglevel=6`? This should show enough of the API commands to give you an idea of what it's doing so that you can recreate.

Comment: I was trying that, is there a way to see the data (body) of what is being set?

Comment: Answering my own question its `--loglevel=8`

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for future reference: 
Run the command as you would on the cli but add `--loglevel=8`. (i.e. `oc tag some.docker.regiery some-image-tag:latest --loglevel=8`).

Then you can see exactly what API call was used and exactly what params were used and you can replicate that! :)